# How do you merge two objects with some properties from one, and other properties from the other?

Tags: javascript, object

I have two objects (some may call them dictionaries) which look like the following:

```
object1 = 
{
     id123: 
     {
           name: Copenhagen,
           type: 'city'
     }
}

object2 = 
{
     id123: 
     {
           name: Copenhagen,
           type: 'county',
           props: { id1: true, id: false}
     },
     id1234: 
     {
           name: Pars,
           type: 'county',
           props: { id1: true, id: false}
     },
     id12345: 
     {
           name: London,
           type: 'county',
           props: { id1: true, id: false}
     },
}
```

If two ids are the same, my merged object needs to take the type from object1, and needs to keep the props from object2, like so (notice Copenhagen):

```
mergedObjects = 
{
     id123: 
     {
           name: Copenhagen,
           type: 'city',
           props: { id1: true, id: false}
     },
     id1234: 
     {
           name: Pars,
           type: 'county',
           props: { id1: true, id: false}
     },
     id12345: 
     {
           name: London,
           type: 'county',
           props: { id1: true, id: false}
     },
}
```

I've tried the following with the spread operator:

```
mergedObjects = { ...object2, ...object1 }
```

But the whole id object is replaced, rather than merged. Can you help?

Comment: The dupe target is a little over the top for this type of objects. Just iterate over the properties of `object1`, check if the same property is in `object2` and store the `type` from `object1` in the corresponding property of `object2`

Answer (score 0):

Go thru the object2 keys, add the values to merged and update `type` from object1 if they have otherwise use the type of object2.

```js
const object1 = {
  id123: {
    name: 'Copenhagen',
    type: "city"
  }
};

const object2 = {
  id123: {
    name: 'Copenhagen',
    type: "county",
    props: { id1: true, id: false }
  },
  id1234: {
    name: 'Pars',
    type: "county",
    props: { id1: true, id: false }
  },
  id12345: {
    name: 'London',
    type: "county",
    props: { id1: true, id: false }
  }
};

const merged = {};
Object.keys(object2).forEach(key => {
  merged[key] = { ...object2[key], type: object1[key] ? object1[key].type : object2[key].type };
});

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: _"Go thru the object2 keys"_ - We need the info from `object1`, so why should we iterate over `object2` where (in this case) 2/3 of the properties are not relevant?

Comment: @Andreas, As in question, merged object has to have "props" from object2 (and object1 does not have "props" key) and overlay the "type" from object1.  This is what I assumed based on the questions expected output.